# Query a datetime field without considering the time in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to update a field when its Create date is from yesterday 2014-09-24 but the update does not happen although the conditions are fullfilled. I guess the problem is the time in the CreateDate field like "2014-09-24 12:25:00" so the match does not work.

How can I compare only for the date?

```
UPDATE MyTable SET SentDate = NULL WHERE Category = 'test' AND CreateDate like '2014-09-24'
```

Comment: Cast the desired date fields to just date data type `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try to convert your column like this:
... AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate,101) = '09/24/2014'

-- SQL Server syntax used for conversion

Another option would be to select a range
... AND  CreateDate >= '2014-09-24' AND CreateDate < '2014-09-25'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET SentDate = NULL WHERE Category = 'test' AND CAST(CreateDate as DATE) like '%2014-09-24%'
```

Comment: Type DATE is not a defined system type. Why?

Comment: Which version of sql server you use ?

Comment: in sql server 2008 it's work , i dont have 2005 for test you query

Comment: This query may be dangerous because the date format will depend on the system configuration (it may be 2014/09/24, 09/24/2014,...)

Comment: @JoëlSalamin he told in question that he have "2014-09-24 12:25:00"  format

Comment: @GeoVIP It was just a remark. If for some reason an admin changes the configuration of the server, this query will not work anymore (i just share one of my bad experience...)

Comment: Just get rid of the like operator and wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd do it this way:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
  SET SentDate = NULL 
WHERE Category = 'test' AND CAST(CreateDate as Date) = '2014-09-24'
```

However, I see you're on Sql Server 2005, and the `Date` type isn't supported until Sql Server 2008. So instead, you should do it this way:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
  SET SentDate = NULL 
WHERE Category = 'test' AND dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, CreateDate), 0) = '2014-09-24'
```

This is typically a lot better than any string-based method for excluding the time portion of a date. Alternatively, you could do this:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
  SET SentDate = NULL 
WHERE Category = 'test' AND CreateDate >= '2014-09-24' and CreateDate < '2014-09-25'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query you're looking for (>= SQL Server 2012):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET SentDate = NULL
WHERE Category = 'test'
    AND FORMAT(CreateDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US' ) = '2014-09-24'
```

Here is the version for T-SQL < SQL 2012:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET SentDate = NULL
WHERE Category = 'test'
    AND SUBSTRING(CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CreateDate, 120), 1, 10) = '2014-09-24'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Minus 1.  Question is tagged tsql which does not have a function named date_format.

Comment: @DanBracuk I fixed it, sorry for the first version that was for `MySQL`